Could not build the application for the simulator - Flutter version 3.24
Error (Xcode): ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/kind-0.5.2/lib/src/kind/uuid.dart:39:3: Error: Type
'UnmodifiableUint8ListView' not found.


I update my flutter code to 3.24, Now I am getting the above error; How can I resolve it.

Upgrade your package by run this in command line:
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions


Run
flutter clean && flutter pub get

Then, run
pod update or pod install --repo-update

